Using UTF-8 Support with ncurses on Windows Powershell in C
I' trying to use ncurses on Windows in C and wanted to use some UTF-8 Characters.
What I've tried so far:
compiled in termux it's enough to use it like this and link it with -lncursesw:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h> 
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    initscr();

    cbreak(); 
    refresh();
    mvaddstr(1, 0, "\xe2\x9c\x93");
    mvaddstr(2,0, "\xe2\x97\x8b");
    mvaddstr(3,0, "\xe2\x97\x8f");
    mvaddstr(4,0, "\xe2\x97\xaf");

    refresh(); //print screen
    getch(); //keep window open
    endwin(); 
    return 0;
}


Everything is as expected.
But on Windows in doesn't work.
To print unicode in  Windows Powershell I needed to set the to set     SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); explicite:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    printf("%s", "\xe2\x9c\x93");
    return 0;
}

But it doesn't work in combination with ncurses (it also not prints unicode characters). I tried it also with setlocale. Nothing helps.
Any suggestions?

The SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); probably has no effect because the MinGW driver allocates a screen buffer.  You might get different results by setting NCURSES_CONSOLE2

Thanks for your reply.
If I have understood correctly, then I have to pass the variable to the compiler as “-DNCURSES_CONSOLE2”, right? (Sorry, I'm really new to C and ncurses)
I tried it that way and it doesn't change the output.

it is an environment variable
